# Installing APC on lighttpd + php 5.2

Tags: 10.04, php, 9.04, lighttpd

I've found this [tutorial](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/socialinguatribe/Integrating_APC_Into_PHP5_And_Lighttpd) to install APC on servers with lighttpd + php 5.2 on Ubuntu 10.

However, when I run `sudo pecl install apc` the package is just downloaded and is not installed. (i.e. I'm not asked the next question" and apc.ini file is not created at all.

If I run only `pecl install apc` I get a warning (no permissions to write some files).

(I need instructions for both 9.04 and 10.04)

thanks

Comment: Which Ubuntu 10? 10.10 or 10.04?

Comment: @Jorge Castro 10.04 But I've just realized that I also need to know for Ubuntu 9.04 (both have php 5.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 10.04, you can just install the php-apc package.  9.04 is no longer supported (see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).  9.10 does have this package as well.  Also, 10.04 has PHP 5.3.2, not 5.2.x.  PHP 5.2 is no longer supported by PHP.  If you need PHP 5.2, Ubuntu Hardy (8.04) will still have PHP 5.2.4 supported until April 2013.